# Why does my NAudio FFT result differ from MATLAB by a factor of 4?

Tags: c#, fft, naudio

The following C# NAudio code produces a different result to MATLAB by a factor of 4. Why does this occur and is one of them incorrect?

```
Complex[] tmp = new Complex[4];
tmp[0].X = 1.0f;
tmp[1].X = 0.5f;
tmp[2].X = 1.0f;
tmp[3].X = 0.25f;
tmp[0].Y = 0.0f;
tmp[1].Y = 0.0f;
tmp[2].Y = 0.0f;
tmp[3].Y = 0.0f;
FastFourierTransform.FFT(true, 2, tmp);
```

NAUDIO OUTPUT:

```
0.6875 + 0.0000i
0.0000 - 0.0625i
0.3125 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0625i
```

MATLAB OUTPUT:

```
2.7500 + 0.0000i
0.0000 - 0.2500i
1.2500 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.2500i
```

Comment: I trust matlab implementation. To find the problem maybe you could use a longer signal with a specific frequency and then observe the spectrum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) and its inverse require a certain normalization so that `ifft(fft(x))==x`. How this normalization is done changes from implementation to implementation.

It seems that, in this case, NAudio has chosen a different normalization than MATLAB.

MATLAB uses the most common normalization, where `fft(x)` at `k=0` is equal to `sum(x)`, and the inverse transform does the same thing but divides by `n` (number of samples). This is also the equation as described in the [Wikipedia page for the DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). In this case, the inverse transform matches the equation for the Fourier series.

NAudio seems to do the division by `n` in the forward transform, such that at `k=0` you have `mean(x)`.

Given the above, you can use the first frequency bin (the DC component) to verify what normalization is used (assuming there is a DC component, if the signal has a zero mean this will not work): If the DC component is equal to the sum of all the sample values, then the "common" normalization is used. It can also be equal to the sum divided by `sqrt(n)`, in the case of a symmetric definition, where the forward and inverse transform carry the same normalization. In the case of NAudio it will be equal to the sum divided by `n` (i.e. the mean of the sample values). In general, take the DC component and divide it by the sum of the sample values. The result `q` is the normalization term used. The inverse transform should have a normalization term `1/qn`.

Comment: I assume this means neither are incorrect and that it would always be unwise to compare the absolute energy/power of am magnitude plot with that computed by 2 different FFT algorithms unless you are sure some kind of level calibration has taken place. Meaning i can continue to use NAudio without the need to make any manual corrections to the complex data.

Comment: @AlexS: The FFT doesn't compute energy or power, it computes the DFT. From there, you can easily compute energy/power, as long as you know the definition of the DFT that your FFT algorithm is using. Note that simply looking at the output for frequency 0 you can figure out what normalization is being used. -- What I mean to say is that, before you add units to any plot, you need to know what you have computed... :)

Comment: thanks, in that case can you please elaborate in your answer on how to confirm the normalisation method using the first frequency bin 0 Hz (or DC), I think this will then prove they are the same and the answer will be complete.

Comment: @Alex: I have added a paragraph on how to examine the normalization. Is this what you had in mind?